# VUE: How to use prop with CSS modules?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vue-component

**row.vue**

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "Row",
    data() {
      return {
        app: [
          "row",
          "row-test",
          "flex-center"
        ]
      }
    },
    template: `
      <div :class="$module[app]"><slot></slot></div>
    `
  }
  </script>
```

**row.scss**

```
.row {
  color: red; 
}
.row-test {
  color: green; 
}
.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <row app="row-test flex-center">my row</row>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

**vue.config.js**

```
css: {
  requireModuleExtension: true,
  loaderOptions: {
    css: {
      modules: {
        localIdentName: 'hex-[HASH:HEX:3]'
      }
    }
  },
  modules: true
}
```

I want to declare my attributes using the app attribute, where they will be written similarly to an ordinary class. Then I want there to be an Array in row.vue, which will add only the values that I define in  and convert them to CSS using CSS modules (class is randomly generated)

**I'm getting this**

```
<div app="row-test flex-center">my row</div>
```

**Expected result**

```
<div class="hex-g3D hex-f41">my row</div>
```

Comment: in `Row` component `app` is declared as data property and in `App.vue` is passed as prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing `app` as prop to `Row` component, define a computed property to return the modules with the different classes:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "Row",
   props:['app'],
  computed:{
   modules(){
     return this.app.length? this.app.map(_class=>{
            return this.$module[_class];
      }):[];
    }
  },
    template: `
      <div :class="modules"><slot></slot></div>
    `
  }
  </script>
```

and pass it like :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <row :app="['row-test', 'flex-center']">my row</row>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: would I be able to declare **app="row-test flex-center"** like this without all those brackets?

Comment: No, it's not possible without brackets and quotes

Comment: and would it be another way without using Array?

Comment: I wanted the prop app to be about the same as the class, i mean declare it like **app="row-test flex-center** etc and convert it to modules. I thought I could use the classic class in this instead of the prop app case? (google translate)

Comment: i think you want that `row-test flex-center` should be a string and it's equivalent to `:class="$module['row-test flex-center']"`?

Comment: equivalent to **:class="[$module['row-test'], $module['flex-center']]"** cause this *$module* must be like Array

Comment: if you put just put `:class="[$module['row-test'], $module['flex-center']]"` does it work?

Comment: Of course, if this **row-test** or **flex-center** is declared like **app="row-test gg"**, then yes it works. I just want me not to have to list everything in row.vue as **:class="[$module['flex-center'], $module['row-test], $module['font-big']]"** etc. I would like it as one variable, and it will only use the values I write in that **app** if u understand me.

Comment: i  edited my answer with some suggestion and i hope that works for you

Comment: sorry i missed to add parenthesis and curly bracket

Comment: still the same error, it looks like he doesn't want to take this **=>** https://ctrlv.cz/tbdb

Comment: sorry i used reserved word `class` change it to `_class`

Comment: Try `return this.app.length?this.app.map(_class=>{
            return this.$module[_class];
      }):[]`

Comment: Well  works, but is here any chance use this app attr as string without  this Array brackets (like i said before) or i cant?

Comment: I'm not sure but try `<div app="row-test flex-center">my row</div>` and in row component add `this.app.split(' ').map(_class=>{
            return this.$module[_class];
      })`

Comment: Oh yes, it works exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot, I love you (no homo). You've saved me days of work before I figure out how it works, I appreciate your help.

Comment: you're welcome, it's my pleasure that i could help you